# Serialization round trip of hash map does not preserve order

Tags: java, serialization

I've noticed that with a recent version of Java (1.7.0_u51) serialization and deserialization of a hashmap no longer preservers the order of the elements in the hashmap. See the below example:

```java
@Test
public void test() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("a1234567", "aaa");
    map1.put("b1234567", "bbb");

    System.out.println("Map1: " + map1.toString());

    byte[] serializedMap1 = objectToBytes(map1);

    System.out.println("Map1 Serialized: " + Arrays.toString(serializedMap1));

    Object map2 = bytesToObject(serializedMap1);

    System.out.println("Map2: " + map2.toString());

    byte[] serializedMap2 = objectToBytes((Serializable) map2);

    System.out.println("Map2 Serialized: " + Arrays.toString(serializedMap2));

    Object map3 = bytesToObject(serializedMap2);

    System.out.println("Map3: " + map3.toString());

    byte[] serializedMap3 = objectToBytes((Serializable) map3);

    System.out.println("Map3 Serialized: " + Arrays.toString(serializedMap3));

    Object map4 = bytesToObject(serializedMap3);

    System.out.println("Map4: " + map4.toString());

    byte[] serializedMap4 = objectToBytes((Serializable) map4);

    System.out.println("Map4 Serialized: " + Arrays.toString(serializedMap4));
}

private byte[] objectToBytes(Serializable obj) throws IOException {
    PoolByteArrayOutputStream bos = new PoolByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        oos.close();
        return bytes;
    } finally {
        bos.close();
    }
}

private Object bytesToObject(byte[] str) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(str);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ClassLoaderObjectInputStream(bis, null);

    Object obj = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    bis.close();
    return obj;
}
```

The above test will output:

```
Map1: {a1234567=aaa, b1234567=bbb}
Map1 Serialized: [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, 17, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 72, 97, 115, 104, 77, 97, 112, 5, 7, -38, -63, -61, 22, 96, -47, 3, 0, 2, 70, 0, 10, 108, 111, 97, 100, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 73, 0, 9, 116, 104, 114, 101, 115, 104, 111, 108, 100, 120, 112, 63, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 2, 116, 0, 8, 97, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 116, 0, 3, 97, 97, 97, 116, 0, 8, 98, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 116, 0, 3, 98, 98, 98, 120]
Map2: {b1234567=bbb, a1234567=aaa}
Map2 Serialized: [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, 17, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 72, 97, 115, 104, 77, 97, 112, 5, 7, -38, -63, -61, 22, 96, -47, 3, 0, 2, 70, 0, 10, 108, 111, 97, 100, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 73, 0, 9, 116, 104, 114, 101, 115, 104, 111, 108, 100, 120, 112, 63, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 116, 0, 8, 98, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 116, 0, 3, 98, 98, 98, 116, 0, 8, 97, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 116, 0, 3, 97, 97, 97, 120]
Map3: {a1234567=aaa, b1234567=bbb}
Map3 Serialized: [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, 17, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 72, 97, 115, 104, 77, 97, 112, 5, 7, -38, -63, -61, 22, 96, -47, 3, 0, 2, 70, 0, 10, 108, 111, 97, 100, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 73, 0, 9, 116, 104, 114, 101, 115, 104, 111, 108, 100, 120, 112, 63, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 116, 0, 8, 97, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 116, 0, 3, 97, 97, 97, 116, 0, 8, 98, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 116, 0, 3, 98, 98, 98, 120]
Map4: {b1234567=bbb, a1234567=aaa}
Map4 Serialized: [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, 17, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 72, 97, 115, 104, 77, 97, 112, 5, 7, -38, -63, -61, 22, 96, -47, 3, 0, 2, 70, 0, 10, 108, 111, 97, 100, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 73, 0, 9, 116, 104, 114, 101, 115, 104, 111, 108, 100, 120, 112, 63, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 119, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 116, 0, 8, 98, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 116, 0, 3, 98, 98, 98, 116, 0, 8, 97, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 116, 0, 3, 97, 97, 97, 120]
```

(Note this only appears to work with map key where the last 7 characters are equal)

From the output above you can see the order continues to change after each serialization round trip.

I understand that the internal order of a map is not guaranteed to be consistent and I am not relying on it but I would have assumed that after serialization round trips the serialized bytes would be identical when the map itself has not changed.

What specifically changed in the JDK to cause this to happen? (Is it a bug in the JDK?)

Is there a way to get consistently get the same serialized bytes for the same hashmap? (without using a different order preserving map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HashMaps are clearly documented as unordered. If you're relying on their ordering you are already doing something wrong.

Comment: I understand that the internal order of a map is not guaranteed to be consistent and I am not relying on it but I would have assumed that after serialization round trips the serialized bytes would be identical when the map itself has not changed. I would like to be able to get consistent serialized data.

Comment: @kazvictor "I would have assumed that after serialization round trips the serialized bytes would be identical when the map itself has not changed." No, `HashMap` offers no such guarantees. Hash buckets use a seed which is random and per-JVM invocation; which means a same `HashMap` can iterate differently from one JVM invocation to another on the same machine.

Comment: You can't assume anything that isn't specifically stated in the Javadoc.

Comment: And the statements 'I am not relying on it' and I would 'like to get consistent serialized data' are mutually contradictory.

Answer (score 5):

A HashMap doesn't have any predictable order. It's thus not a problem if serialization changes the order it happens to have. Note that doing any change (add, remove) in the map will also change its order.

If insertion order matters, then you should use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: I understand that the internal order of a map is not guaranteed to be consistent and I am not relying on it but I would have assumed that after serialization round trips the serialized bytes would be identical when the map itself has not changed. I would like to be able to get consistent serialized data.

Comment: @kazvictor Why do you need consistent serialized data? If that is necessary you may already be trying an approach that could be re-done in a better fashion.

Comment: The map has itw own serialization format, that avoids consuming too much bandwidth. When it's deserialized, the buckets are not reconstituted identically.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to be able to get consistent serialized data.

If you need that, then you will need to use a different data structure.  The `HashMap` class does not give those guarantees.

In any simple hash table, the observed order of the entries depends on:

- the size of the table,
- the order in which elements are added and removes, and
- the actual values returned by the `hashcode()` function.

The first two you could (in theory) control when serializing / deserializing if you wrote a custom `Map` based on hash tables.  But the last one is outside of your control.  So if one of your keys has (for example) a hash code that depends on an identity hashcode, then you cannot preserve the iteration order ... no matter how you serialize / deserialize.

In your case, you appear to be serializing / deserializing a `HashMap<String, String>`.  That is one cases where order preservation is theoretically possible across Java versions.  (The algorithm for hashing a Java String is *specified* ...)  However, I can't see how you would achieve it using `HashMap` ... short of grubbing around in the classes private internal data structures.

In short, use `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap` if you need the order of elements to be preserved across serialization / deserialization.